# How to package a single use executable in Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have some executable file that can perform some analysis on supplied file and outputs result to stdout. Something like for example `ffmpeg` but it is called many times per second and performs much easier task. How do I package that so that other containers can call and use it? Do I need to wrap it into daemon and talk to other containers via http or something like that? Or do I spawn a new container for each call?

Comment: You have two options: base images for those other containers on the image that includes your binary, then they can call it directly, or implement any sort of network or file-based (via shared volumes) trigerring of your binary from what is essentially another OS. If you cannot control the base images for those other containers, you only have one option.

Comment: This sounds like something you don’t want to require root-level access to run, and you don’t want to run it in an isolated filesystem, and you’d prefer the command line be shorter than longer.  These make it sound like not a good candidate for running in a container.

Comment: The app that calls this executable is a server that processes user uploads, so I already have at least one container. The reason I wanted to separate them is to be able to independently configure and update them, and not to mix a php server with a python executable.